# fvm flutter errors are cached when I switch flutter version

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, fvm

I use FVM for my project. I have installed 2 different versions of flutter, 3.3.9 and 3.7.12. Whenever I switch from one version to another, I get to see the errors from the version I switched to. I have tried flutter clean, flutter pub get. But still nothing. Any suggestion of how to solve my problem? I use visual studio code

running `fvm flutter doctor` I get the following:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 13.3 22E252 darwin-x64, locale en-GR) 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0) 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3) [✓] Chrome - develop for the web 
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3) 
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2) 
[✓] Connected device (3 available) 
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

So, I switched from 3.7.12 that was working fine, back to 3.3.9. On problems tabs of VSCode I see problems related to 3.7.12 version.

Comment: Please edit the post adding the errors you get. Also a `flutter doctor` log from each fvm version would be useful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. Just invalidate the cache and `fvm flutter clean` fixed the issue in my case.

Comment: which command invalidate the cache?

Comment: I have used `flutter pub cache repair` before I execute all other commands but issue still remains